# ValueError: Objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape, I am trying to plot a bar graph with 3 bars at a time but getting this error

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below are the values I am trying to plot on Single graph with 3 bars at a time.

averaged precision  is [0.3408782254413762, 0.4431790795129584, 0.44562855758681447, 0.6930575070252911, 0.7048203106429318, 0.7076336331481228, 0.5817814329884687, 0.5915420288865595, 0.7056966148161392]

recall is [1.0, 0.39345726247142776, 0.18316722513975484, 0.36019465995952776, 0.047896671507928194, 0.10484171589149509, 0.04886434702343402, 0.08009139022931534, 0.2240637724379194]

fscore is [0.5084402430790007, 0.41684067176950357, 0.259621799568279, 0.47402819742590835, 0.08969784843837761, 0.18262590836627177, 0.0901563785388454, 0.14108119734411395, 0.3401328941951721]

```
barwidth = 0.4
k = 10

fig = plt.figure()
index = np.arange(k)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

rect1 = ax.bar(index,precisionKlist,barwidth,color='b',align = 'center')
rect2 = ax.bar(index+barwidth,recallKlist,barwidth,color='g',align = 'center')
rect3 = ax.bar(index+(2*barwidth),fscoreKlist,barwidth,color='r',align = 'center')

ax.xlabel("k values")
ax.ylabel("BcubedScore")
ax.title("Bcubed Scores for UnNormalized Data of KMedian")
ax.legend(rect1[0],rect2[0],rect3[0],('precisionKlistr','recallKlist','fscoreKlist'))

def autolabel(rects):
      for rect in rects:
          h = rect.get_heightd()
          ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2.,1.05*h,'%d'%int(h),ha='center',va='bottom')
      
      
autolabel(rect1)
autolabel(rect2)
autolabel(rect3)
```

Comment: What is your barwidth ?

Comment: its 0.4 @ KnowledgeGainer